# Rendering data from node in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am having problem rendering data sent from node in jade.

this is how my route looks like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('about', {aaaa: 'do not touch my data'});
});
```

and in jade I am doing something like this (read in other questions) :

```
extends layout

block content
   p #{aaaa}
```

Seems like it solved other people problems but not mine. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? Does nothing show? Do you get an error? Something else?

Comment: it shows nothing. no output on page. only things from layout

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct -- I suspect the issue might be your template inheritance -- are you sure the `layout.jade` file you're extending has a block called `content` available?